# Display message on same page if username and password is correct

Tags: php, html

I'm developing an application which requires a username and password before log in. I'm using dreamweaver for the development. What i want to achieve is when the user enters the correct username and password he should get a message saying "username and password correct" , if wrong credentials "username or password wrong". 
But with the Dreamweaver log in server behavior it cannot do that, what it does is to redirect to a page when credentials are right or wrong. can someone help me?

HTML

```
  <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
        <tr>
          <td><label for="username"></label>
            <input name="username" type="text" class="register-input" id="username" data-role="none" placeholder="Enter your username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="password"></label>
            <input name="password" type="text" class="register-input" id="password" data-role="none" placeholder="Enter your password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Sign In" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
        <tr>
          <td><div align="center"> </div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php require_once('Connections/db.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "test.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "error.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = true;
  mysql_select_db($database_catchapp, $catchapp);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=%s AND password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $catchapp) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Change the header location (At the very bottom part of your php code)? Unless you don't want the page to refresh at all, then you'd need to use AJAX, although I'm unsure whether it's a good idea / possible with sessions / login. (Or simply just remove the `header()` location completely)